# Access result of Elixir Plug.Parsers.JSON

Tags: json, http, elixir, plug

I am writing a small http server using Elixir Plug and having some trouble understanding how its parser works. I cannot figure out how to access the result of the parser in my router. I currently have

```
...
plug Plug.Parsers, parsers: [:json],
                json_decoder: Poison
plug :match
plug :dispatch
forward "/admin" , to: VoucherSite.Admin.AdminRouter
...
```

And in the admin router I want to access the parsed result from the Parser called above

```
put "/user" do
  ...access result here...
  respond(conn, {:ok, ""})
end
```

It feels like I am missing something obvious but all I have access to is `conn` which is the connection so no idea how to get the parsed body from the request.

Comment: You can reach decoded json with `conn.params`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Plug`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.html) is a `behaviour`, having 2 callbacks: `init/1` and [`call/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.html#c:call/2). The latter receives a [`Plug.Conn`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html) struct and returns *possibly modified* `Plug.Conn` struct. That allows to *chain* plugs.

[`%Plug.Conn{assigns}`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#module-connection-fields) is intended to be used to update the map between calls to different plugs.

[`Plug.Conn` implements](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#module-protocols) the `Inspect` algebra out of the box, so just do:

```
Logger.debug inspect(conn)
```

somewhere and you’ll see where the parser stores the body (I would bet it’s some key in the `assigns` map.)